# Redirect domains with subfolders drops slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I do want to add www to all requested domains. This works fine so far as long as I don’t use subfolders.

Example: http://domain.fr redirects to http://www.domain.fr but http://domain.fr/panel drops the slash, redirecting to a wrong url http://domain.frpanel

Here is my rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.fr$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for helping me

René

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://www.domain.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```